# Can't create a Flutter/Firebase non-authenticated user favorite list in ListTile

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, staggered-gridview

I am trying to create a NON-authenticated user icon 'select favorite' option where if an icon is clicked ( on a list of titles in a ListView of Firestore data(book titles)) it saves the data to be routed to a new favorites page. I can not find information on how top do this in the Firestore docs, but I found a youtube tutorial that does this for a popular flutter WordPair app. Here is the string used to store their WordPair data:

```
final _randomWordPairs = <WordPair>[];
```

and another variable to check to see if WordPair lists were already saved is:

```
final _savedWordPairs = Set<WordPair>[];
```

If my Firebase data string is

```
Firestore.instance.collection("titles").snapshots()
```

what is the equivalent to the above WordPair variables so I can create this favorites list with a list of my titles

```
snapshot.data.documents[index]['title']
```

Nothing works. Still trying to figure it out: variables:

```
final savedDb = Firestore.instance.collection("books").document('title');
```

final alreadySaved = Firestore.instance.collection("books").document('title');

ListTile code to call it:

```
trailing: Icon( alreadySaved ?  Icons.favorite :
                        Icons.favorite_border,
                        color: alreadySaved ? Colors.red : null),

                          onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if(alreadySaved) {
                              savedDb.remove('title');
                            }else{
                              savedDb.add('title');
                            }
                          });
                        }
```

I tried this but now it just crashes that page;

```
final alreadySaved = Firestore.instance.collection("books").where((item) => item.contains("title"));

List<String> savedDb = ['Firestore.instance.collection("books").document(title)'];
```

---

```
                              trailing: Icon( alreadySaved == null ?  Icons.favorite :
                          Icons.favorite_border,
                              color: alreadySaved != null ? Colors.red : null),

                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              savedDb.add('title');
                            });
                          },
```

Last attempt:

bool alreadySaved = false;

```
savedDb() async{
    DocumentSnapshot ds = await         
Firestore.instance.collection("books").document('title').get();
    this.setState(() {
      alreadySaved = ds.exists;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    savedDb();
  }
```

and onTap says .remove and .add isn't defined for type Function,  and my icons won't even change color. This is impossible

```
                            onTap: () {
                          setState(() {
                            if(alreadySaved) {
                              savedDb.remove('Firestore.instance.collection("books")');
                            }else{
                              savedDb.add(Firestore.instance.collection("books"));
                            }
                          });
                        },
```

Returns .remove and .add isn't defined for type Function

Comment: Can you add something more about it, as It's hard to understand your problem and I don't know what do you want to achieve. Can you share the link to the tutorial? What do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: Yes, on a flutter tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1gDhl4leEzA&list=PLillGF-RfqbYeckUaD1z6nviTp31GLTH8&index=56&t=0s , at time 44:40 he shows how he codes, very simply, a 'favorite' list using heart icons where a user can click on a heart and it will save the listtile to a new page route.

I have been trying to add a similar 'favorites list' to my project but can not figure out how to do this with my firestore data.

Answer (score 0):

All information about datatypes in Firestore you can find [in this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types).

For `_randomWordPairs` which is actually an array -  you can just use the same type. Array is one of supported field types in Firestore. So there shouldn't be any problem with that.

When it comes to `_savedWordPairs` its more complicated as this is a set which means it cannot contain duplicate values. So during the update of the field that contain this list you  have to add logic which will check if the particular value already exits before adding to the list.

Of course there is no custom type WordPair possible to be stored in Firestore, but you can store its string object and there are a lot of possibilities to do this: as list, as map or just as String or even as some nested object. Firestore is generally NoSQL database based on documents so you can do everything there. If you need more about Firestore data model check [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model). Or just take a look on general reference for "NoSQL based on documents database" , as Firestore implements all standard concepts of these db types.

I hope it will help!

Comment: I just can't comprehend this. Nothing in those docs are clear to me on how to add logic to see if a value already exits. '.contains', '.exists', nothing works. I updated my code above to include my firestore variable and method and the errors are 'Conditions must have a specific type of bool' and 'the method .add isn't defined'. I also tried .set and .get. I looked at https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#non_bool_condition but I just can't figure this out. It is way over my skill level, yet that video was so simple for wordpairs.

Comment: Does anyone know where I can find a flutter expert in firestore to help me figure this out so I can understand it?

Comment: Which package do you use to connect with firebase?

Comment: Do you mean the database contents? What else is a package?

Comment: I meant what do you have in import statements of your project?